# Node.Js - Passport - Express Validator - req parameter is Undefined

Tags: node.js, express

First, i have this in my route, i need to use Passport to Authenticate the User Sign Up Process :

```js
router.post('/user/signup', passport.authenticate('local.signup',{
  successRedirect: '/user/profile',
  failureRedirect: '/user/signup',
  failureFlash: true 
}));
```

I'm learning Node JS from Youtube Video, in the tutorial, there is a step to create Folder called "config", and inside the "config" folder, there is a file called "passport.js".

The problem is, there is "req" parameter inside one of the function in this "passport.js". When i try to run my program, there is an error that said, "req is not defined". this is the source code of "passport.js" :

```js
var express = require('express');
var passport = require('passport');
var User = require('../models/user');
var LocalStrategy = require('passport-local').Strategy;

passport.serializeUser(function(user, done){
  done(null, user.id);
});

passport.deserializeUser(function(id, done){
  User.findById(id, function(err, user){
    done(err, user);
  });
});


passport.use('local.signup', new LocalStrategy({
  usernameField: 'email',
  passwordField: 'password',
  passReqToCallBack: true
}, function(req, email, password, done){ //here is the problem
  console.log('REQ :');
  console.log(req);
  console.log('password :');
  console.log(email);
  console.log('email :');
  console.log(password);
  console.log('done :');
  console.log(done);

  req.checkBody('email','Invalid Email').notEmpty().isEmail();
  req.checkBody('password','Invalid password').notEmpty().isLength({min:4});
  var errors = req.validationErrors();
  if(errors){
    var message = [];
    errors.forEach(function(error){
      message.push(error.msg);
    });
    return done(null, false, req.flash('error', messages));
  }
  
  User.findOne({'email': email}, function(err, user){
    if(err){
      return done(err);
    }
    if(user){
      return done(null, false, {message: 'Email is already in use.'});
    }
    var newUser = new User();
    newUser.email = email;
    newUser.password = newUser.encryptPassword(password);
    newUser.save(function(err, result){
      if(err){
        return done(err);
      }
      return done(null, newUser);
    });
  });
}));
```

How to bring the req to fill the parameter in the passport.js ?

Comment: are you loading a signup form first it the routes ?, I mean there should be a get for signup page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The parameter is called `passReqToCallback`, not `passReqToCallBack` (notice that the `b` needs to be lower-case).

Comment: Thank you very much brother!